# Swoole send websocket data from server to client

Tags: php, websocket, swoole

**Hi all!**

I use swoole for WebSockets.

**I create clietn part:**

```
<script>
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://site.ll:9502/?user=tester01');
    ws.onmessage = function(evt) { console.log(evt.data); };

    ws.onopen = function (event) {
        ws.send('test');
    }
</script>
```

**Create WebServer part:**

```
$server = new swoole_websocket_server("127.0.0.1", 9502);

$server->on("start", function ($server) {
    echo "Swoole http server is started at http://127.0.0.1:9502\n";
});

$server->on('open', function($server, $req) {
    echo "connection open: {$req->fd}\n";
});

$server->on('message', function($server, $frame) {
    echo "received message: {$frame->data}\n";
    $server->push($frame->fd, json_encode(["hello", "world"]));
});

$server->on('close', function($server, $fd) {
    echo "connection close: {$fd}\n";
});

$server->start();
```

**Create send from server part:**

```
$client = new swoole_client(SWOOLE_SOCK_TCP);
if (!$client->connect('127.0.0.1', 9502, -1)) {
    exit("connect failed. Error: {$client->errCode}\n");
}
$client->send("hello world\n");
echo $client->recv();
$client->close();
```

I trying to create TCP server inside WebSocket server, just adding next part inside "on start" callback:

```
$server2 = new swoole_server("127.0.0.1", 9503);
$server2->on('connect', function ($server2, $fd){
    echo "connection open: {$fd}\n";
});
$server2->on('receive', function ($server2, $fd, $from_id, $data) {
    $server2->send($fd, "Swoole: {$data}");
    $server2->close($fd);
});
$server2->on('close', function ($server2, $fd) {
    echo "connection close: {$fd}\n";
});
$server2->start();
```

But Just receive an error:

> Swoole\Server::__construct(): eventLoop has already been created. unable to create swoole_server.

I need to send data from server to client. How can I do this?
In workerman library I doing next:
https://github.com/Shkarbatov/WebSocketPHPWorkerman/blob/master/worker.php

Comment: could you implement? I have the need to transmit data continuously, from a TCP socket client to the clients connected to the websocket server.
I am using openswoole.

Answer (score 0):

Upload working result on github: https://github.com/Shkarbatov/WebSocketPHPSwoole

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `addListener` function instead of the `new swoole_server`.

the doc is here: 
`https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/modules/swoole-server-methods#swoole_server-addlistener`